# Plone 4 Table View Work Around

Tags: python, plone

I'm writing a custom view to get around the bug that displays the wrong start and end times for events in table view in Plone 4. However, when I call my view I get the following error:

> Traceback (innermost last):
>     Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 116, in publish
>     Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 498, in traverse
>     Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 343, in traverseName
>     Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 110, in publishTraverse
>     Module zope.component._api, line 122, in queryMultiAdapter
>     Module zope.component.registry, line 240, in queryMultiAdapter
>     Module zope.interface.adapter, line 522, in queryMultiAdapter
>   TypeError: `__init__`() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

It's been awhile since I've created a view, but I thought (in accordance with [this](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-community-developer-documentation/views/browserviews#creating-a-view)) that `__init__()` does take 3 arguments (self, context, request). At any rate here's what my BrowserView class looks like at the moment:

```
class NewEventsView(BrowserView):
    """Custom View for displaying events in a table with correct times"""

    implements(INewEventsView)

    def getCurrentEvents(self):
        """Method to return all active events in order"""
        current_events = []
        cat = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_catalog')
        brains = cat(portal_type='Event', review_state='published', sort_on='start')
        for x in brains:
            event = x.getObject()
            if event.startDate > DateTime():
                current_events.append(event)
        return current_events
```

I've tried different variations of this adding an `__init__` as in the above mentioned page shows, and just for the heck of it giving it an `__init__(self, context):` just to see if 2 arguments would really change anything and it gives the exact same error.

I'm testing this in a Plone 4.0.2 site on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (in a python 2.6.6 virtualenv)

BrowersView registration from browser/configure.zcml (I threw this into a theme I was also working with). I call http://localhost:8080/plone/events/new_events_view to see how the view looks and get the above error. I've also tried registering the view in portal_types for topic and it will give me that error upon navigating to http://localhost:8080/plone/events until I remove the view.

```
  <browser:page
      for="*"
      name="new_events_view"
      class=".newEventsView.NewEventsView"
      template="newEventsView.pt"
      permission="zope.Public"
      allowed_interface=".interfaces.INewEventsView"
      />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I know it's a small block of code, but rip it apart if you think it could be done in a better fashion, I'm a student always looking for ways to improve.

Thanks

Comment: For the record: the traceback states that the `__init__` method found only takes 2 arguments while the caller tried to pass in 3. Make of that what you will.

Comment: Yeah I caught that, I'm not sure where this `__init__` is though because as I stated above regardless of how I change the `__init__` for my view I get the same result.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the ZCML registration for this view, and where you imported BrowserView from? Also, what URL are you using to access the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put any code in the `__init__` method of a browser view anyways. If you want to have some custom code put it into methods on the view class or overwrite the `__call__` method. The view is instantiated before a security context is available and might be instantiated multiple times per request. This can lead to a lot of surprising effects if you do any non-trivial work in it - so best just avoid doing anything in there.

In Plone 4 you would write a custom `__call__` as:

```
from zope.publisher.browser import BrowserView

class MyView(BrowserView):

    def __call__(self):
        # do some work
        return super(MyView, self).__call__()
```

Comment: You led me to an answer, although I didn't need the `__call__`. I had been using the wrong BrowserView apparently (from Products.Five import BrowserView). As soon as I changed that my work around the plone bug worked like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A much better workaround would be to customize the `formatCatalogMetadata.py` skin script from the ATContentTypes skin layer.

Replace the line reading:

```
if same_type(value, '') and value[4:-1:3] == '-- ::':
```

with:

```
if same_type(value, '') and (value[4:-1:3] == '-- ::' or value[4:19:3] == '--T::'):
```

and the event view tables work again for events.

Comment: This works for correcting the formatting of the effective date for an event, but the Start and End dates remain 4 hours off. In the portal_catalog for a test event the start date reads "2011/04/09 11:00:00 GMT-4" but in the tableview for the events it reads "Apr 09, 2011 07:00 AM"

Comment: The script in question appears to be ignorant of timezones; this could definitely do with some improvement.

Answer (score -1):

But it's **python**!

The definition for a class method is:

```
def __init__(context, request):
```

`self` is understood by default (because the method is called as `Class.__init__(context,request)`) (or, again, shortened to `Class()`).

Comment: Come again? `__init__` is not a classmethod, and does most definitely take a self parameter!

Comment: You're right, I wrote it backwards.  The **def** takes a self parameter, but you don't _pass_ the **self** parameter, because it's implicit.